# Excel- replace cell with value from a cross ref cell based on pattern

Tags: excel

Sorry to ask this,but please point me in the right direction.I'm a total newbie on excel and trying to learn it.I have situation where in a i have to create a report from a master sheet which has the below format.

```
**Order#        Step#                Assignee#        Status#**
OA1#            Step1.Initiate New   John             Completed
OA1#            Step2.Close New      Missing          In Progress
OA1#            Step3.End            -                Pending for previous step
OA2#            Step1.Initiate New   Sean             In Progress
OA2#            Step2.Close New      Missing          Pending for previous step
OA2#            Step3.End            -                Pending for previous step
```

I want to put a filter on step2 and step3 and should be able to see the assignee name.Can someone tell me how can i replace these(step2 and step3 value has to be overwritten based on step1 assignee) based on the step1 assignee? The master sheet has few hundreds of such entries.
Appreciate your help.

Comment: Assuming the assignee is column C, use a separate column (we'll pretend column F) and put this formula in that column row 2 (so in this example cell F2) and copy down: `=IF(A2<>A1,C2,F1)`  Then you can either hide the assignee column and use the new one you've created, or copy the new column -> right-click the assignee column -> paste special -> values to overwrite with the updated values.

Comment: Thank you.The problem is , there will  be close to thousand Orders.How do I copy the formula for all orders?The reference cells cannot keep up.It should be based on Step# as well.Order number is repeating,for those step#1 assignee has to be copied against all other steps against that particular order.